# How to populate an asp listbox with multiple values with LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My listbox doesnt appear data, only the classdata name:

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(XMLfile);
    List<ClassData> data = (from item in doc.Descendants("freq")
         where item.Element("ID").Value > 50
         orderby item.Element("Time").Value
         select new ClassData
         {
              ID= item.Element("ID").Value,
              Name= item.Element("Name").Value,
              Age= item.Element("Age").Value,
              Time= item.Element("Time").Value
          }).ToList<ClassData>();
    lstBox.DataSource = data;
    lstBox.DataBind();
```

myclassdata:

```
 public class ClassData
{
    public string ID{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Age{ get; set; }
    public string Time{ get; set; }
}
```

I add 4 items in my listbox with same name of my classData Items...
my result is: SolutionName.ClassData 32 times (number of results)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <asp:DataList ID="dataList" runat="server"
        RepeatColumns="1"
        RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
        RepeatLayout="Table">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table border="1" >
                <tr>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' Width="50" /></td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' Width="20" /></td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Age") %>' Width="200" /></td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Time") %>' Width="200" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 1):

defaultly, the listbox displays the result of `ToString()` of the items you provided, which is 'SolutionName.ClassData' like you said.
To change that, you need to change the `DisplayMember` property of the listbox- `listBox.DisplayMember = "Name"`
for asp.net listbox, it's `DataTextField`

Comment: sorry, i missed the asp.net bit. i've edited my answer accordingly

Comment: OK, but apear only 1 value in the listbox. I need appear all the 4 values like " ID:56 Name:John Age:60 Time:09:00 "